# Jobs ad - should this link take me to the "6 more benefits"

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

This link (shown in image below) takes me to the company page instead of to the benefits section (anchor) of the company page.  It is sort of misleading, when someone reads +6 more benefits and its a hyperlink they get the impression that they will see those benefits when they click the link.  But upon clicking this link it simply takes me to the company page:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/meridian

[image]

Comment: I agree. I saw the same "+ 6 more benefits" on another company's ad and it also took me to that company's page. To me, that just seemed like click-baiting.

Comment: I guess it's kind of the same thing with the "see who you'll be working with" ones.

Comment: At the least it should move your screen to the benefits section of their page. Does it not?

Comment: That's what I am asking for, and no it does not.  The proposed solution is to anchor it.  I wouldn't have posted this if it did.

Comment: We agree it's a little confusing, and we're discussing. Likely options are: 1. make it link straight to the benefits section, or 2. make the text look less like an individual link.

Comment: or, 3. make clicking on that show/hide that 6 more points in that place with no navigation..

Comment: Frankly the first time I saw this my immediate thought was the link would cause the list to simply expand similarly to how the see more comments link on a post works. In hindsight quite silly given it's an ad, but still I think the +X more benefits should just be stylized like the list and simply be the last item in the list (maybe the icon for this entry in that listcould just have a + sign in it) with the Learn More button as a link to the company page being sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The solution we settled on was to remove the blue link-like color:

[image]
<sup>Changing the color obviously didn't take two weeks. It just got lost in our todo list, sorry.</sup>

We didn't really want to link directly into the benefits section. Making the section expandable is interesting, but requires more effort than we're current willing to commit to the feature. However, we'll keep it in mind the next time we make larger changes.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't take two weeks? Finding the exact right shade of grey can be time consuming... :)

Comment: I dont mind that you don't implement my change but I think its real strange to even mention "+2 more benefits".  Either don't show the text at all or simply show all the benefits, but to say "+2 more benefits" and not make it clickable to the benefits section is pointless.